# Could not open Repository at "/etc/sw/keys"

Tags: php, linux, centos, subdomain, plesk

I have a centos server with Plesk. I am creating a subdomain by putting an entry through /usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain --create subdomainname.

When i run the complete command through command line, than the subdomain created successfully. Now i want to done it through php file, so i am using shell_exec.

But when i try to run it, i got following error:

Could not open Repository at "/etc/sw/keys": Cannot open file
Unable to connect to database: get_admin_password() failed: file_get_contents() failed:

I know that there is file permission issue, but didn't know where to look. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have a permission problem accessing `/etc/sw/keys` from php. This is just what the error tells you. And it is not surprising, since php is (most likely) executed with the permissions of your http server process which probably has no rights to access files under `/etc`.

Compare this attempt to the one you made on the command line: which user account did you use in that case? What permissions? You need the same permissions, regardless of which shell or scripting language you are using. You might want to try to use the `sudo` utility or even phps `suexec` extension, but keep in mind that this might open huge security issues! There are good reasons why administrative stuff is executed with lower permissions than web page scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to take risk with my server security. I had check the permission and give same user permission to both files. But still didn't work. Is there any other way by which i can run command /usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain --create subdomainname.

Comment: _What_ permissions did you specify for `/etc/sw/keys`? And what are the permissions of `/usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain`?

Comment: My first error is resolved. Now i am getting error: Unable to connect to database: get_admin_password() failed: file_get_contents() failed:

Comment: `/etc/sw/keys Permission: drwxrwsrwx. 7 root swkey-data` and `/usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain Permission: lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root`

Comment: What kind of permissions are _those_ meant to be? World writable? And carrying the sticky bit for the root group? The second one is only a symbolic link, what does it point to and what are the permissions of that physical file?

Comment: Oh, and just a thought because of the error messages content... Could it be you are asked for the password in an interactive manner? That certainly cannot work from within a php script. At things would be much more complex then just executing the utility.

Comment: the second one is pointing to `/usr/local/psa/admin/plib/api-cli/subdomain.php` and its permission is -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root. I am a beginner in linux so don't know about all groups and owner permisison, thats why asking for help.